# The set of infinite sequences with finitely many nonzero values is dense.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, reference-request, normed-spaces

[image]

Could I get a proof to this lemma or a reference if a proof is too time consuming?

Comment: Can you please remind me what $\ell^{p}(\mathbb{N})$ is?  Sequences that converge to $0$ in the $p$-norm? with entries in $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: (i) is immediate, and (iii) follows from (ii) and the fact that $l^p({\mathbb N})$ contains elements in which infinitely many $x_k$ are nonzero, so let's consider (ii). For (ii), pick $\{x_k\}$ in $l^p({\mathbb N}),$ and note that each of $(x_{1},0,0,0,\ldots),$ $(x_{1},x_{2},0,0,0,\dots),$ $(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},0,0,\dots),$ etc. belongs to $V$ (why?) and they form a sequence in $V$ that converges to $\{x_k\}$ (why?). (Hint: What do you know about the tails of a convergent series?)

Comment: @TravisJ It's the set of $\Bbb C$-valued sequences with finite $p$-norm

Comment: @Monolite does Dave's comment answer your question sufficiently, or are you looking for something more explicit?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. @Omnomnomnom I understood (i) still not so sure on (ii). It is the first time I am dealing with this kind of subspace.  I can understand it intuitively but I am unsure how to prove convergence to ${x_k}$ rigorously In Daves comment.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Could you make the argument explicit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $x = \{x_k\}$ denote an arbitrary sequence in $\ell^p$.

For $j \in \Bbb N$, let $x^{(j)} = \{x^{(j)}_k\}$ denote the sequence given by
$$
x^{(j)}_k = 
\begin{cases}
x_k & k \leq j\\
0 & k > j
\end{cases}
$$
Note in particular that $x^{(j)} \in V$ for all $j$.

**Claim:** In the space $\ell^p(\Bbb N)$, $x^{(j)} \to x$ as $j \to \infty$.

**Proof:** We note that
$$
\|x - x^{(j)}\|_p^p = 
\sum_{k=1}^j |x_k - x_k|^p +\sum_{k=j+1}^\infty |x_k|^p
=\sum_{k=j+1}^\infty |x_k|^p
$$
However, since $x \in \ell^p$, the sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_k|^p = \|x\|_p^p$ converges.  It follows that $\lim_{j \to \infty} \sum_{k=j+1}^\infty |x_k|^p = 0$.  Thus, $\|x - x^{(j)}\|_p \to 0$ as $j \to \infty$.

Thus, we have $x^{(j)} \to x$ as $j \to \infty$, as desired.